# formatting the email input field

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to format my input field to help the users get a better understanding of what they have to write in a input field.

What I'm looking to do is to show say "example@domain.com" when they start typing and while they type the @ will stay until they type it and the same with the domain. I have achieved this on my input type tel by using the jQuery Masked Input Plugin (http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

Does anyone if there is a plugin for this or how I can achieve this?

Thanks a bunch folks! :)

Comment: Does "Your e-mail address" need any hints even? :)) By the way I don't want the UI to mess with me typing my mail address because I'm used to type the `@` and I would need to edit further - just use the `placeholder` attribute.

Comment: *I have achieved this on my input type tel by using the jQuery Masked Input Plugin* -- what's the problem then?

Comment: @Juhana How did you do that? From what I can tell the jQuery Masked Input Plugin only supports numbers...